# Connecting 2 line plots

Tags: python, graph, line

Hey all I was wondering how could I connect 2 different line plots on the same graph together in matlab?

If that is not ideal then I could combine the 2 dataframes together however then I would need a way to tell it to change the color of the line plot at a certain x point?

I want to indicate were the predicated sales are on the graph. here is a Picture of what my code and graph currently look like(Red is actual/green is predicted)

[image: Actual and Pred Sales]

Here is the link to my ipython notebook https://github.com/neil90/Learning_LinearReg/blob/master/Elantra%20Regression_Practice.ipynb

My original dataset was 50 observations(small I know), I split it into training and test. I got .72 R2 on my test set. So then I looked online to see if I could find the independent variables for 12 months after the dataset and low and behold I was able to, however(I am not sure of the accuracy). I then wanted to predict the sales with my model. Hence the green line.

Comment: (1) is this MATLAB or Python? The code doesn't look like MATLAB to me, but I might be wrong. (2) Can't you just add the last sample known value to the predicted vector?

Answer (score 0):

That is always possible to connect two points using a single plot command both in MATLAB and in Python, such as:

```
P1 = df1(:,end); % last Point in The First Plot
P2 = df2(:,1); % first Point in The Second Plot
plot([P1(1,1) P2(1,1)],[P1(2,1) P2(2,1)])
```

**But**

this is **not a good practice**, as you said the green graph is your prediction part. Why don't you include more inputs when calculating the predicted points.

So I assume that you have a set of data, and then you divided it in two parts, a part for training and the other part for testing the learned model.

The ratio should be (70% to 30%  or 80% to 20%), unless you have a validation part as well.

So after you train your model on the training part of the data, you should check the error of the model (Does it converge?). As I can see your prediction part has a huge error. It cannot even re-generate the sample it has seen before (i.e. the last point on the red graph).

So first try to plot the prediction over the whole training data, to see how accurate the learned model is. I am pretty sure that you need to reduce the learning error for your model by doing more iterations or changing the structure of the model.

Because you have not mentioned enough details most of the ideas are based are assumptions here.

Comment: Ahh okay so let me clarify, the green porition is not from a split on the dataset. I created a new df with independent variables I found online(the independent variables were values I could look up online I.e. Unemployment rate/CPI etc) Then tried to predict what the sales would be for new df(test2 in the screenshot). The original df with the sales has the sales up until February 2014, my test2 df I had values for March 2014 to February 2015.

Comment: Please do what I suggest. First train  the model on the data and report the learning error in the question. This way we can understand that the algorithm is converging. Secondly, sometimes the data are so different that the prediction without any a priori knowledge is not a good solution.

Comment: Okay so here is the ipython notebook https://github.com/neil90/Learning_LinearReg/blob/master/Elantra%20Regression_Practice.ipynb I have my train and test dataset and my R2 on the test is .72.

Comment: Please, edit your question with the new information.